# Ionic Firebase Login with Facebook taking too much time on Android device

Tags: angularjs, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-authentication, facebook-authentication

I am trying to implement a login with Facebook in my Ionic app. I built an apk and run it on my Android phone, and when I press the login button it takes about one minute to login and sometimes does not even work. Here is the function:

```
 facebookLogin(){
   if(this.platform.is('cordova')){
   Facebook.login(['email', 'public_profile']).then((res) => {
    const facebookCred = firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.credential(res.authResponse.accessToken);
    firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(facebookCred).then((res) => {
        let currentUser = firebase.auth().currentUser;
        window.localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(currentUser));
        this.navCtrl.pop();
    },(err) => {
      alert('Login not successful: ' + err);
    });
  });
}}
```

I hope someone can tell me why that is happening and suggest a fix for it. Thank you for your time!

Comment: can you try to debug your app with chrome dev tools ? and see what errors in console while running  apk to your device.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your suggestion. I ran ionic cordova run browser and in Chrome some error showed up when trying to login with Facebook. I solved it by adding http://localhost:8000/index.html in my facebook developer console in "Valid OAuth redirect URIs". Now it runs very smoothly in browser, but on my phone it acts the same.

Comment: Are you using the latest version? There was a bug around 3.9.0 which caused some delays.

Comment: My firebase version is 4.1.3, angularfire2 is at version 4.0.0, and Ionic is at version 3.5.0.